# Django Inline Forms with three 3 models

Tags: django-models, django-admin, django-3.0

I need help to figure out how to display all related forms inline on the Django admin panel. I have seen some examples with 2 forms but when I add the third form it breaks. I am learning using python3  and django 3

```
class Exam(models.Model):
      exam_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Question(models.Mode):
      question_content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      exam_id = models.ForeignKey(Exam, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Option(models.Model):
      option_question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      is_answer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      option_value = models.CharField(max_length=240)

# Admin models
class OptionInline(admin.TabularInline):
      model = Option

class QuestionInline(admin.TabularInline):
      model = Question
      inlines = [OptionInline]

class ExamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      inlines = [QuestionInline,]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use nested inlines without a third party app. This [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9025) goes over it.

There appears to be a few packages to solve this: [django-super-inlines](https://github.com/BertrandBordage/django-super-inlines) and [django-nested-admin](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin).